# Is there a Java JSON parser that does not interpret values (just returns the value tokens)

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need a Java JSON parser that doesn't make any attempt to parse property values.  We have a separate schema that will be applied later and I don't want any assumptions to be made by the parser.  For example,

```
{ fred : "5" }
```

should be parsed as

```
{ fred : 5 }
```

if the schema says that fred is an integer.  I want to avoid a two step process where the parser makes assumptions that the schema later corrects.  Ideally I just want the original tokens returned for values.

I could write a parser but I would prefer to use an existing maintained project if one exists.

Comment: `{ fred : "5" }` isn't valid JSON.  And any parser that treats the "5" in `{ "fred" : "5" }` as numeric rather than string is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object to do this:

```
Object name = (Object) jsonObject.get("fred");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if such a parser is out there but I think you can definitely construct one. I'm assuming that the data is a JSONObject and not a JSONArray but the idea could be definitely extended.

Make a JSONObject of the input, use the keys() function to get an enumeration of the keys, loop over it (initialize an empty JSONObject before looping), use the get() method and type caste it to java.lang.Object, then use the put(,) method on the other JSONObject that you're making.

Something like that should get what you want.